# Как перенести объект на Wear?

Tags: java, android

Если брать официальную [инструкцию](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/assets)

то там в примере показано как передать растровое изображение в поток байтов.
А как быть если мне нужно передать не изображение в поток байтов а apk файл который будет находится в локальной директории приложения `content:///android_asset/test.apk`? Сколько байтов нужно указывать если приложение весит 4мб, 4 ляма?